# Access Error Run-Time 2447 Insert into table

Tags: vba, ms-access

The Error shows its there is an Invalid of the . (Dot) Or ! operator

```
If IsNull(Me.m_1) Or IsNull(Me.u_1) Or Me.m_1 = "" Or Me.u_1 = "" Then
      MsgBox "Please add all needed info"
Else
     sqls = "INSERT INTO User_access (Application_ID, Modul_ID, username_ID, Clock_ID, Assinged_date, Assinged_by, Request_number) values('" & Me.A_1 & "', '" & Me.m_1 & "', '" & Me.u_1 & "', '" & Me.Clock_ID & "', '" & Date & "', '" & Me.Assinged_by & "', '" & Me.Request_number & "');"
     DoCmd.RunSQL sqls
End If
```

I cannot see any error within the code So please Help me

Comment: `& "', #" & Date & "#, '" &` (in Access, Dates are surrounded by `#`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Date()`:

```
sqls = "INSERT INTO User_access (Application_ID, Modul_ID, username_ID, Clock_ID, Assinged_date, Assinged_by, Request_number) values('" & Me.A_1 & "', '" & Me.m_1 & "', '" & Me.u_1 & "', '" & Me.Clock_ID & "', Date(), '" & Me.Assinged_by & "', '" & Me.Request_number & "');"
```

And no quoting of *numeric* values.